# Pagseguro pedindo para enviar um senderEmail mesmo eu tendo enviado

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um cUrl e enviando os dados via checkout transparent para o pagseguro. Estou testando usando a **sandbox**, até ai funciona direitinho, o problema é que no campo **senderEmail** só funciona se eu passar um email do pagseguro, se eu passo um email do gmail por exemplo, recebo uma mensagem dizendo que o **senderEmail** é requerido

> Assim funciona:

```
"senderEmail"       =>  "teste@sandbox.pagseguro.com.br"
```

> Assim não funciona:

```
"senderEmail"       =>  "teste@gmail.com"
```

Eu pesquisei no forum deles e encontrei outras pessoas com problema parecido e nenhuma delas foram respondidas

Comment: Se funciona com um determinado email e outro não, é o caso de contactar o suporte da empresa realmente e/ou verificar a documentação - note da documentação que para usuário não cadastrado, deve realmente ser usado o domínio do sandbox: https://devs.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v1/reference e, no mesmo link, tem opção de acesso ao usuário cadastrado (especifico)

Comment: O suporte é horrível, nem respondem. A documentação é outro problema grave deles, lá por exemplo diz que vários campos são opcionais, mas na prática são obrigatórios. No caso do endereço do cliente, a documentação cita todos aqueles campos como opcionais e diz que usando o "shippingAddressRequired" como false, esses dados não são obrigatórios (sendo que são)

Comment: De fato, praticamente tudo dessa empresa aí é sofrido. Eu já normalmente nem pego pra fazer trabalhos que o cliente queira serviços deles e, se por acaso pegar, ponho um custo extra nesse caso e deixo claro o motivo.

Comment: Então pelo que entendi, no ambiente de testes eu preciso usar um email de alguém cadastrado ou então o email fornecido por eles, porem no ambiente real, eu vou poder usar um email de alguém que não é cadastrado no pagseguro?

Comment: Então... é a impressão que a documentação dá, mas nunca se sabe né :D - e o pior, amanha ou depois pode mudar. Felizmente recentemente eu consegui tirar umas pessoas do pagseguro e migrar pro mercado pago, outros pra cielo (agora funciona independente do mercadolivre), que é "menos pior". Como vc já leu, vou apagar meus ultimos 2 comments aqui.

Comment: Eu cai de paraquedas nesse projeto, ao final do projeto o cliente me pediu para integrar o pagseguro, essa é a primeira vez que trabalho com essa API, ate ai parecia tudo tranquilo, a documentação parecia boa...isso só até eu começar a integrar, depois fiquei quase uma semana com dor de cabeça referente a problemas com a integração, mas agora só falta eu resolver esse problema do email mesmo

Comment: Pode deixar os comentários amigo, eu achei útil

Comment: então fiz um pagseguro a alguns dias, ta funcionando normal, se vc estiver no sandbox e obvio que ele so vai aceita o email de teste. agora quando tirar ele do sandbox ele vai aceitar outros email, pois esse email é referente a sandbox que eles criarão pra sua conta...

Comment: Opa, obrigado por me esclarecer essa duvida, Willian.